# How to change HttpWebRequest cookies?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebresponse

`Cookies` in a `HttpWebRequest` are read-only but I need to change some of cookies.

I can use `Set-Cookie` header but it's error-prone. Is there anyway to change a `HttpWebRequest` cookies in a `OO` way ?

If no, how can I get the header text of a `System.Net.Cookie` ? (I will use it in `Set-Cookie` header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest targetrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targeturl);
targetrequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
foreach (string clientcookie in Request.Cookies) {
    Cookie targetcookie = new Cookie(clientcookie, Request.Cookies[clientcookie].Value, "/", targetrequest.RequestUri.Host);
    targetrequest.CookieContainer.Add(targetcookie);
}
```

Comment: The problem is `CookieCollection` in `targetrequest` is not sync with `targetrequest.Headers`. If I manipulate the collection it would not affect the `Header` string.

Comment: Set-Cookie is a header that comes from the server, for a request you should be be setting the Cookie header

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=VS.90).aspx

You need to initialize the CookieContainer object and add your cookies to it.

If you get cookies from a HttpWebResponse simply add the collection to the CookieContainer  (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.add(v=VS.90).aspx).

To change one specific cookie you should access it and change its values:

```
cookies["cookie_name"].Expiration = ...
```